# PHP -file_exists() Function?

Tags: javascript, php

I am using PHP `file_exists()` function to check whether a file exists or not:

```
<script>
var getval=<?php echo file_exists("Settings.ini"); ?>;
if(getval)
{
 // If file exits   
 // Reading values from Settings.ini file and intializing form element
}
else
{
 // If file doesn't exist
 // Initializing form element with default values
}
</script>
```

This code is working fine and I am able to initialize the form element with values from `Settings.ini` file if the file exists.
But if the file does not exist, then I am not able to initialize the form element with default values. i.e control not going into else block.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `var getval=<?php echo json_encode(file_exists("config.php")); ?>;` Here you go!

Comment: Please try with var getval='<?php echo file_exists("Settings.ini"); ?>';